# My Route with path :id is not working with react route v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After clicking on table one item it should open `item/1` but it is not doing this after I update this from version 5 of React Router. This is the code which was working before with older version. What do u guys think what I am doing wrong here?

```
{menuItems.map((x: MenuItem, index: number) => {
                    const res: JSX.Element[] = [<Route key={index} path={x.url} element={<x.component history={history} />} />];
    
                    if (x.children && x.children.length > 0) {
                        for (const child of x.children) {
                            res.push(
                                **<Route key={index} path={`${x.url}${child.url}`} element={<child.component history={history} />}** />
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(res);
    
                    return res;
                })}
```